# Compression Supply-Stop-Valve Rotates After Installation

Tags: plumbing

[image]

A [traditional compression valve](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-Compression-Inlet-x-3-8-in-Compression-Outlet-1-4-Turn-Angle-Valve-G2CR19X-C1/202047059) is in the process of being replaced.

I am bothered by the fact that the entire valve rotates axially.  It is however tight enough so that when I pull it along the axis it does not slip off.  Should the valve's body be able to rotate at the connection point (rotate about the pipe)?

I could try tightening the nut, however, I think I am at the limit.  Is there anything that can be done to pin the valve relative to the 1/2 inch pipe?

Comment: once compressed it should not rotate

Comment: also you need two wrenches, of which one holds the body

Comment: I thought so, if rotating that means it is not tight enough?   I am using two wrenches.   Thanks

Comment: did you insert the compression ring the right way

Comment: Uncertain, how can one insert it incorrectly?  How to insert ring the right way? Did not realize that there was a wrong way to insert.

Comment: it should be facing the valve with nut pushing it towards the valve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142357/discussion-between-gatorback-and-ruskes).

Comment: Ohh! I think you are asking is the compression ring between the nut and the valve body?   If that is the question, Yes,  the ring is "sandwiched" between the nut and the valve's body.   Is that what you are trying to understand / ask?

Comment: @Armand  Interesting!  This could explain the rotation.  Odd that the previous valve used the same compression ring and was OK for 20 years.    Not sure what to use for a valve at this point.    What are the other options?  I would prefer to avoid gluing a stop valve as they need to be replaced periodically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the standard valve you show on PVC pipe. It compresses the ferrule onto the metal pipe to make a seal; PVC is too weak. Some valves will work with PEX pipe as long as you insert a special reinforcement ring insert inside the PEX to support the ferrule. From this item: "Compatible with copper or PEX (PEX installations require a stainless steel tube insert)" Also, it's often a bad idea to re-use the compression ferrule, as it gets deformed slightly when originally clamped down.

Not sure exactly what kind of (water supply?) pipe you have. I haven't seen standard PVC used for that. CPVC pipe does exist for that type of use - maybe you have that? Here's a sample shutoff designed for use with CPVC:

This CPVC Inlet valve requires CPVC gluing
[image: CPVC Inlet valve requires CPVC gluing]

To avoid gluing, a push connect shut off valve may be compatible with CPVC supply stub. Here's an example instruction set for such a valve.

[image]

Comment: It's either PVC or CPVC coming out of the wall.   I'd like to avoid gluing it, so that if I have to replace the valve in the future, I do not have to cut the pipe.  Maybe a shark bite?

Comment: @gatorback Sounds good as long as it's rated for that (probably needs the tube insert shown). I modified the answer to reflect this.

Comment: There is a fitting on the end, you can simply swap the valve at the compression fitting in the future

Comment: If you get a Sharkbite, be sure it is described as fitting the type of pipe you have. You cannot simply specify the size, e.g., 1/2" PVC requires a different Sharkbite from 1/2" copper. The size is a nominal specification and these pipes are NOT 1/2" outside diameter. Also you must smooth the outside edge of the cut end. I recently used a rasp to smooth the cut end of 1/2" PVC water pipe at a neighbor's house prior to forcing on a Sharkbite plug with the water on. This was an outside pipe cracked in a freeze. Find out if the same Sharkbite fits both PVC and CPVC, if you don't know wht yours is

Comment: I ended up using an [shark bite 1/2 to 3/8 angle stop](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-Brass-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-x-3-8-in-OD-Compression-Quarter-Turn-Angle-Valve/1000182523) from Lowes.   Cleaned the pipe with sandpaper to ensure a good seal.